# Can Access Website But Not text File In SubDirectory

Tags: c, http, sockets, http-headers, cygwin

I'm a newbie to socket programming and am trying to read an online dat file that is nested in a website directory. I can connect to the main website but not any of its subdirectories or the text file I am trying to access in one of them.

ie I can connect to www.mainsite.com but not www.mainsite.com/dir1/dir2/textfile.dat. I would like to read the text file using recv or read, and I don't mind accessing it a different way like say fdopen ect...

I am writing this in gnu c with cygwin on a windows 7 machine.

In the interests of privacy I'll use an anonymous website name. Parts of the code I am using is posted below -thank you:

```
  if(getaddrinfo("www.mainwebsite.com","80"    /*this works as it stands and fails if  I use  
                  , &hints, &res)!=0)       www.mainwebsite.com/subdir/textfile.dat  */
  .......
  .......
  /*create new socket*/
int newsocket = socket( res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, 0);
.....
int newconnect = connect(newsocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a web client is a lot more complicated than just `connect`ing to the directory.  Once you connect to `www.site.com` you'll need to `write` an HTTP `GET` request for the file you want, and then `read` the response (which should include the content of the file).

The text of the `GET` request will look something like this:

```
const char *req = "GET /subdir/textfile.dat HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.site.com\r\nUser-Agent: myprogram\r\n\r\n";
write(newsocket, req, strlen(req));
```

This is a Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP) request.  There's a lot more to learn if you really want to know how HTTP works.  Start with the Wikipedia pages and then branch out from there....

If you're less interested in understanding exactly how HTTP works, you can look into [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) which is a very popular library which implements HTTP, making life a lot easier for people (like you) who want to write simple clients without getting into the ugly details.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. It seems you can use all the HTTP commands like GET via the send funtion and then use recv to, in my case, read the file I was trying to open. (dancing bannana emoticon)!